# how to add the touch area of a button?

Tags: ios, uibutton

```
selectgroup = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
selectgroup.frame  = CGRectMake(screenWidth/4-23/2, 158, 23, 23) ;
selectgroup.hidden = NO;
UIImage *selectgroupimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"groupicon2.png"];
[selectgroup setBackgroundImage:selectgroupimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[selectgroup setcontentEdgeInsets : UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 150, screenWidht/2, 30)];
[selectgroup addTarget:self action:@selector(selectgroup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:selectgroup];
```

I want to increase the clickable area of the button to `(0,150,screenwidth/2,30)`.
I have try to set `contentEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeinsets` but both doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you  mean by clickable area? You can tap any where on button it will call its action.

Comment: increase the touch area

Comment: Are you want to increase the width of button?

Comment: If I increase the button width  the image will goes wrong

Comment: Add your image in UIImageView and then add button with clear background, make button as big as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set image like (Button property setImage and setBackgroundImage both are different)

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[buttonObject setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then Set button frame you want

```
buttonObject.frame  = CGRectMake(0,150,screenwidth/2,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIButton, Or category/extension,, and use it like this:

```
-(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44, -44, -44, -44)), point);
}
```

Comment: what is self.bounds ?

Comment: @WaitakJong self = your button. You should add this method on a subclass of UIButton, This method is ovvriding UIButton functionality.